# Memory never releases on Heroku, slow memory leak from models in Django?

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I have been troubleshooting memory leak issues on my Django application deployed to Heroku. Basically, when the app is deployed/dyno restarted RAM hovers around 40% then as soon as someone gets on, it goes to 80% usage then stays there and never goes back down. Here is a screenshot of my last 24 hours:

[image]

Things I have tried:

- Caching expensive things that are called often (using
  `@cached_property`), like checking a users subscription that is tied
  to their organization.
- Optimizing my queries, so far the biggest queryset I bring back is
  ~20 rows and isn't particularly big.
- Ran a memory profiler (pympler) that has a tab on Django Debug
  Toolbar. Admittedly am unsure of what I am looking at.
- Lowered gunicorn workers to 2 instead of 4
- Checked that database connections weren't going haywire (currently 2
  connections)

Some other ideas of what it could be but unsure how to properly troubleshoot:

- I have middleware where I check for a subscription that runs on most pages, could this be somehow leaking/storing data?
- If I hit a 3rd party API (which isn't that often in this app) do I have to actively run `del` to get it out of memory?

Has anyone else ran into this issue? I read somewhere that using `@property` on models can fill up your memory. I do use them quite heavily but I thought caching the expensive ones would be worth it. Any guidance/ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Unlucky you did not give any substantial information that could lead to an answer. The cause of the memory usage can most likely be found in the output of the memory profiler.

Comment: @KlausD I am happy to add more context to it as well! What would be the best way to output some of that data here? I'm new to memory profiling and I know having `DEBUG=True` adds to the memory on every request right? I think that's why I was wasn't 100% sure what to look for.